# ask for string to store, and store in linked list with prints, scanf

Tags: c, string, linked-list

i got this pretty simple build code with three different approches to store a string in a linked list node, but the second isnt working

i created first the struct node

```
struct node
{
    char *data;
    struct node *next;
};
```

and i have a printList function

```
void printList(struct node *pointer)
{
    while (pointer != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s ", pointer->data);
        pointer = pointer->next;
    }
}
```

than the basic stuff like head, second and third to NULL;
and head, second and third MALLOC;

```
struct node* head = NULL;
struct node* second = NULL;
struct node* third = NULL;

head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
second = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
third = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

this is my first attempt, witch is working fine:

```
char tmp[3]; //3 just for the testcase, and demonstration
printf("What do you want to store: ");
scanf("%s", tmp);
printf("This is stored in tmp: %s\n\n", tmp);
head->data = tmp; 
head->next = second;
```

this is my third attempt, also working just fine:

```
third->data = "cool";
third->next = NULL;
```

this would be the most important one, but I cant get it fixed...

```
printf("What do you want to store: ");
scanf("%s", second->data);
second->next = third; 

printList(head); //calling the print function
```

the reason I doing this step by step instead in a loop is, to see what's going on at which point...
I know that I could use the 1st attempt for the 3rd one, but is there a way to not use the temporary string store, why cant I say:

the user wants: "google"(%s) stored in second->data; and done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your working cases, you set aside memory for the string that `data` points to; in the second, you do not (`scanf` puts the string in the space you pass to it).  You set aside space for the node (which `second` points to), but not the `data` field within it.

Note that when you set aside space, you have to set aside enough to hold the string you will put there (including the trailing `\0` character).

Comment: but didn't I set space aside with
second = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));


where is the difference between sotring it first in a tmp, an assigning tmp to data, and asking with scanf an user to store his string in data??